# Split text from a string/file into a two-dimensional array based on "/n" and ". " for paragraphs and sentences.

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, split

I need to take text from a document or a string (from text pasted by the user), and split it into a two dimensional array where each section is a paragraph and the values within are the sentences. I am doing this as a winform if that affect anything.

So far I have it so I can make a basic array holding the text of each paragraph as distinguished by "\n" (This does result in things like headers being on their own but that is fine). But I need to also have each sentence separated by ". " and the mentioned two-dimensional array formed.

my code so far is:

```
public void sentenceSplit()
    {
        content = File.ReadAllText(documentPath);
        content = Regex.Replace(content, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        string[] paragraphs = content.Split('\n');            

        TextboxSummary.Text = string.Join("\n \n", paragraphs);
    }
```

The Regex is needed as it removes fully empty lines which otherwise are added as array entries due to cases on double "\n".

I've not dealt with creating a 2d array like this before, and am unsure if it can be done in one line where I just declare 2 split values instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you possibly want a jagged array for this as each paragraph can have a different amount of sentences in it. Jagged arrays can be thought of as an array of arrays and have a different syntax from normal multidimensional arrays in C#. [MSDN for Jagged Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

Here is how I would approach your question using jagged arrays.

```
content = File.ReadAllText(documentPath);
var paragraphs = content.split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[][] results = new string[paragraphs.Length][];

for(int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    results[i] = paragraphs[i].Split(new char[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

You can avoid having to use the Regex by using the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` configuration option as it will remove all strings that only contain whitespace, `\n` strings included.

Now, accessing `results[0]` will give you an array of all strings in paragraph one and so on.

Some caveats. None of the sentences will have periods anymore, but you can add those back easily enough. If a period shows up in the middle of a sentence, say in a decimal number, those will be considered separate sentences. I'm sure someone with far more Regex knowledge than I have could give you a split regex that will work better at finding the end of sentences.

Comment: This sounds perfect its been a while and forgot 2d-array needed same amount of values in each. I've also found a Regex expression which should act as ". ". Only issue is that the "StringSplitOptions" isn't accepted in the loop, giving the error "System.Array doesn't contain a definition" for it.

Comment: ah changed it to comma space StringSplitOptions, which seemed to be the right syntax, then that makes it give the error for the results variable at "new string[results.Length][];" as it is an "unassigned local variable"

Comment: Both of those issues were caused by typos. They should be fixed now. Originally had `string[][] results = new string[results.Length][];` which makes no sense. Now reads `string[][] results = new string[paragraphs.Length][];`